# Div not showing after being hidden JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't seem to make a div appear after making it invisible in `onload` in the body. This should be simple to fix, I just can't seem to figure it out.

**PHP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<?php include '/include/init.php'; ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jqeury.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/accounts.js"> </script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
<title>Accounts</title>
</head>

<body onload="hide_buttons()">
    <div class="accounts_headerDiv">
        <div class="ahd_left">
            <img src="/images/launcher2.png" class="accounts_logo"/>
            <p class="title_para"> Accounts </p>
        </div>
        <div class="ahd_right">
            <div class="searchDiv">
                <p class="searchPara"> Search </p>
                <input type="text" id="search_input" placeholder="search" class="search_input"/>
                <img src="/images/search_icon.png" class="search_icon"/>
            </div>
            <div class="userDiv">  
                <a href="#"><img src="/images/default-portrait-icon.jpg" align="right" class="user_picture"  /> </a>            
                <p class="userInfo"><?php username($db);?></p>
                <a href="/functions/logout.php"> Log out </a>                                              
            </div>
            <div class="adminUserButtonsDiv" id="aubd">
                <input id="createUser" name="createUser" value="Create" type="button" class="admin_button">
                <br />
                <input id="editUser" name="editUser" value="Edit" type="button" class="admin_button">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
    <hr />
<?php if (is_admin($db) === 'true') { ?>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/admin.js"> </script>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The `hide_buttons()` function is in accounts.js here

```
function hide_buttons() {
    $('#aubd').hide();      
}
```

Then I want to make the div reappear when I call admin.js which holds this function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#aubd').show();
});
```

The overall goal here is to check if the user has the role of "admin" and hide or show the div and buttons contained within based on this check. So what am I doing wrong? Also is this the correct way or should I be using `AJAX` for this?

Comment: can you verify that hide_buttons() is actually being called?

Comment: btw, why not having div hidden in CSS from the beginning?

Comment: @josh yes, its working

Comment: @Sergio that is a better idea I think

Comment: I agree with @sergio most people do style="display:none;" on page load. otherwise you're going to see the element flash real quick and then hide.    Loads your scripts renders the DOM and then executes your JavaScript to hide the element.

Comment: @Sergio Thanks, It's clear that you are correct and I was honestly more worried about the "correct way" then getting this to work, So I appreciate the input

Comment: @i_me_mine, yes, I think so too. I posted it also as an answer "just for the record".

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping out

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `onload` event happens *very* late in the page load cycle. jQuery's `ready` callback happens much earlier (normally). So what's happening is that your `show` call is happening before your `hide` call.

The best fix is to not use `onload`. Instead, just output the div hidden:

```
<div id="aubd" style="display: none">....
```

Or in your CSS:

```
#aubd {
    display: none;
}
```

Then your `ready` handler will show it just fine.

---

If you can't change the `onload`, you can change `admin.js` so it calls `show` later:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#aubd').show();
    }, 0);
});
```

The `setTimeout` with the very, very short timeout value is there to avoid race conditions with the `load` event handlers. (jQuery hooks up the handler via `addEventListener` / `attachEvent`. Some browsers fire the `onload` handler first, and then the `addEventListener` / `attachEvent` handlers. Others do it the other way around.) But again, it's best to avoid this entirely by hiding the div differently in the first place.

Comment: why not (function() {
        $('#aubd').show();
    })() or direct $('#aubd').show();

Comment: @Ankit: That would get called immediately when the `admin.js` script was reached during the parsing of the page, even earlier than the jQuery `ready` callback, and so it would have the same problem the jQuery `ready` callback has.

Comment: thank you sir. I will accept this asap. Do you think this is the correct way to do this? I'm fairly new to JQuery. So I want to get into good habits early. Or should I just hide this using css and then only make one JQuery call?

Comment: @i_me_mine: *"Or should I just hide this using css and then only make one JQuery call?"* That's what I'd do, yeah.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/eyuviv/1 function running on onload not during parsing,please let me know if i am doing something wrong

Comment: @Ankit: From your comment it wasn't clear where you were putting that function. Yes, if you assign it to `window.onload`, it will (probably) run on window load. Except in your example, your function wouldn't get called if the OP did that, because it's above the `<body>` tag and the `<body>` tag's `onload` will overwrite it. (`window.onload` and the `onload` on the `<body>` tag are the same thing, and it can have only one value). Examples: http://jsbin.com/idohun/1, http://jsbin.com/idohun/2 (Note the order of things.) But again, we don't want to use `onload` at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can put show statement in window.load instead of DOM ready so that it is executed after admin.js is loaded

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#aubd').show();
});
```

As [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) pointed out there is race condition in event that could be avoided using setTimeout.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#aubd').show();
    }, 1);
});
```

Comment: The problem there is you have a race condition. Does the browser fire the `onload` first, or does it fire the handler hooked via `addEventListener` / `attachEvent` (which is what jQuery uses) first? the answer is: It depends on the browser. So I would not recommend ignoring the race condition.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder for pointing such situation, is setTimeout to avoid that condition in your answer?

Comment: @ adil: Yes, that's right, although my primary answer is "don't use `onload` to hide the div in the first palce". :-) (Use an inline style or CSS instead.) Then the `ready` handler will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion, which might fix your problem is to have it hidded in CSS.

Using `#aubd {display:none;}` then the element is hidden already when the page loads, avoiding sometimes showing up and being hidden flashing.

This fixes it and I think it's a better way to code. The answer "why" it doesn't work I think [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17764272/2256325) answered.